# How to show the trace relation: $\text{Tr} [A\not x A ^{\dagger} \not x]\geq0$

Tags: linear-algebra, physics, mathematical-physics

A speaker from a talk/lecture I attended recently quoted the following inequality without proof, and for no good reason I have taken it upon myself to prove it:

---

Let $A\in SL(2,\mathbb{C})$, so $\det\left(A\right) = 1$. Also, let $\not x \equiv x^\mu \sigma_\mu$ where $x^\mu=(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$ is an arbitrary real-valued four-vector (tuple of 4 real numbers) and $\sigma_\mu=(\sigma_0,\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3)$ are the usual [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) with:

$$\begin{align}
\sigma_0&=-\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\\
&\\
\sigma_1=\sigma_x\hspace{0.7cm}\,\,\,\sigma_2&=\sigma_y\hspace{1cm}\,\,\,\sigma_3=\sigma_z
\end{align}
$$

I would like to prove the following harmless looking inequality:

$$\text{Tr} [A\not x A ^{\dagger}\not x]\geq0$$

---

### My progress:

I know that the trace is definitely real, and so the inequality is well-defined:

$$\begin{align}
\text{Tr}[A\not x A ^{\dagger}\not x]^*&=\text{Tr}[(A\not x A ^{\dagger} \not x )^\dagger]\\
&=\text{Tr}[(\not x )^{\dagger}(A^{\dagger})^{\dagger}(\not x )^{\dagger}(A)^{\dagger}]\\
&=\text{Tr}[\not x A \not x A ^{\dagger} ]\\
&=\text{Tr}[A\not x A ^{\dagger} \not x]
\end{align}$$

Honestly, apart from this I don't know what I could do. Hints and/or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\sigma_3$, $A=\mathrm{i}\sigma_2$. Then $\det A = 1$, so $A\in\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{C}$. Nevertheless
$$\begin{split}AxA^{\dagger}x&=(\mathrm{i}\sigma_2)\sigma_3(\mathrm{i}\sigma_2)^{\dagger}\sigma_3\\
&=\sigma_2\sigma_3\sigma_2\sigma_3\\
&=-\sigma_2^2\sigma_3^2\\
&=\sigma_0\end{split}$$
whence
$$\mathrm{Tr}\,AxA^{\dagger}x=-2\text{.}$$

Comment: Thanks, clearly the inequality is false. I'm thinking now, should the inequality sign be reversed, or is any such inequality invalid?

Comment: It's true when $x$ is a positive-semidefinite (psd) matrix, which is the case whenever $x^{\mu}$ is a spacelike or lightlike vector. For then $x$ has a psd square root $y$ and the trace is of the form $\mathrm{Tr}\,B B^{\dagger}$ where $B= y  A y$.

Comment: "..which is the case whenever $x^\mu$ is a spacelike or lightlike vector." how did you arrive at this? And what convention are you using when you say "spacelike"? I think the 4-vector $x^\mu=(0,0,0,1)$ is definitely spacelike, but you have shown that the trace is negative with that choice.

Comment: Sorry, I was hasty and mixed up spacelike and timelike :/. By direct diagonalization, the eigenvalues of $x$ are $-x^0 \pm \sqrt{(x^1)^2+(x^2)^2+(x^3)^2}$. For $x$ to be psd, we need the eigenvalues to both be nonnegative, whence $x^0\leq 0$ and $\lvert x^0\rvert\geq \sqrt{(x^1)^2+(x^2)^2+(x^3)^2}$—a timelike vector.